# How to generate the set of all permutations of a list in Python without repetition

Tags: python

Take the list [1,2,3], I would like to be able to find all ordered combinations of this list without repetition that are the same length as this list. In my case, I need to be able to generate (1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1). How can I go about doing this? I cannot seem to find a function within itertools to allow for this to happen.

I have tried to use other parts of itertools to generate all the possible lists of n items, but found this scales poorly for large n.

Comment: "*this scales poorly for large n*": how large? This is not the function that scales poorly but rather the number of combinations that explodes.

Comment: @mozway I fixed this duplicate closure. Please pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.permutations` is your friend:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> list(permutations([1,2,3]))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```